# Remove media files after removing an object

Tags: python, django

Hey Guys I wanna remove media files automatically after removing related objects.
What can I do?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post/images')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django-cleanup

```
    pip install django-cleanup
```

Then, add django_cleanup in settings.py.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
    )
```

Here is the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `django-cleanup` https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/
You will find all the instructions on the page.